# Closed source alternative to Linux?

Tags: unix

Is there any closed source alternative to Linux that's still actively used and developed? I'm looking for a good, expensive Unix-like OS please. The only other OS's that come to my mind are the various BSD's like FreeBSD, OpenBSD etc., and they're all open source, which simply won't do.

Comment: .......but why?

Comment: out of interest why is 'expensive' desirable, and what's wrong with 'open source'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris (Oracle), AIX (IBM) and HP-UX (HP) are commercial Unix implementations.

Comment: There's also [that which we don't speak of](http://www.sco.com/products/unixware714/), for completeness sake.

Comment: Are they still alive?  Btw., other brands of commercial Unix that came to my mind are True64 and IRIX, but I have no idea whether those are still alive.

Comment: @countermode the last release of IRIX was 2006, and Tru64 is dead too, as HP transferred most of its useful features over to HP-UX.

Comment: Unixware was last updated in 2008, so it can be considered dead too. The small business version is a fantastic product - it allows for 1 user and a phenomenal 1GB of RAM :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a lot less expensive than you're after, but by your definition [OSX](https://www.apple.com/nl/osx/) (with server add-on) would also fit the bill.